# Automatically generating content by databinding to an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I need some help with wpf. What I basically want to do is to fill a expander with a collection (from databinding) of ItemsControls which contains 2 images and and a textbox.
I couldn't get the expected result. Can someone help me with it please?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Expander Name="OnlineExpander"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Header="Online Friends"
          IsExpanded="True">
  <Expander.Content>
    <Grid>
      <ItemsControl Height="50"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="30"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Background="Brown"
                  Name="itemGridTemp">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"
                                  Name="PictureColumn" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="271*"
                                  Name="NameColumn" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"
                                  Name="StatusColumn" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Image Height="30"
                     Width="30"
                     Source="{Binding Path=Image}"
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                     MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter"></Image>
              <TextBox Name="txtName"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Width="271"
                       Foreground="#FFEEB8B8"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
  </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

and the codebehind:

```
private List<Friend> _Friends;
public List<Friend> Friends { get { return _Friends; } }
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  Image img = new Image();
  img.RenderSize = new Size(30, 30);
  img.OpacityMask = Brushes.CadetBlue;
  _Friends = new List<Friend> {
            new Friend{Name="John Smith",IsOnline=true,Image=img},
            new Friend{Name="Name Surname",IsOnline=true,Image=img},
            new Friend{Name="Name2 surname2", IsOnline=false,Image=img}
            };
  OnlineExpander.DataContext = Friends;
}
```

and I have a class called `Friend`:

```
public class Friend {
  private Image _Image;
  private String _Name;
  private bool _IsOnline;

  public Image Image { get { return _Image; } set { _Image = value; } }
  public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } }
  public bool IsOnline { get { return _IsOnline; } set { _IsOnline = value; } }
}
```

I hope someone could help me. and sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: what is the expected result? What are you seeing currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set ItemsSource on your ItemsControl as

```
      <ItemsControl Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

This will generate your Items

Comment: and is it possible to do same thing without the Itemcontrol? Just directly bindingig the items in the grid?

Comment: itemsControl are meant to do these things...grid can't

Answer (score 1):

Your ItemsControl needs to know what items it has.  It won't do this unless you set an ItemsSource (either in codebehind or in markup). Try this instead:

XAML (the ItemsControl now has a name):

```
<Expander Name="OnlineExpander"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Header="Online Friends"
          IsExpanded="True">
  <Expander.Content>
    <Grid>
      <ItemsControl Height="50"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Name="OnlineItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="30"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Background="Brown"
                  Name="itemGridTemp">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"
                                  Name="PictureColumn" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="271*"
                                  Name="NameColumn" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"
                                  Name="StatusColumn" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Image Height="30"
                     Width="30"
                     Source="{Binding Path=Image}"
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                     MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter"></Image>
              <TextBox Name="txtName"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Width="271"
                       Foreground="#FFEEB8B8"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
  </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

Codebehind (the ItemsSource is set to `_Friends`):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = new Image();
    img.RenderSize = new Size(30,30);
    img.OpacityMask = Brushes.CadetBlue;
    _Friends = new List<Friend> {
        new Friend{Name="John Smith", IsOnline=true, Image=img},
        new Friend{Name="Name Surname", IsOnline=true, Image=img},
        new Friend{Name="Name2 surname2", IsOnline=false, Image=img}
    };
    OnlineItemsControl.ItemsSource = _Friends;
}
```